# How can I extend a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive w/ a template that will work in 90% of scenarios. However there are some scenarios where I'll need additional fields be added to the template. Is there a way to extend or modify an existing html template so that adding additional fields is a possibility without rebuilding 90% of an existing template

Comment: Can you not use the component in the other component. Composition is what web components are all about.

Comment: I can. In my mind I was hoping for a way to slot the additional fields into the same area as the directive's main content. For instance, if a general field A is set to X then for this single scenario add this additional field B directly under A. Maybe there's some simple way to do this, but the only way I can think up is to provide an array of field definitions to the base directive and also an array of additional field definitions, provided from extender directives and then generate the base template via repeater logic. Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Actually, you got me thinking. I looked into some of the capabilities of bootstrap 4 and they have an ordering feature. Theoretically I can minimize styling on the base directive and apply ordering attributes based on a key value array directive binding. Then directives composing w/ the base directive could provide the order array specific to their needs and add their new fields w/ the order required to fit it in. I think this could work... but I feel it could be made better still. Just can't put my finger on how.

Comment: @AdrianBrand the problem I'm running into w/ this is from what I can tell, is that even if the base directive is exclusively a series of inputs, the directive content will always be provided in a container, either as the directive name or a replaced div. As such there's seemingly no way of inserting additional inputs into the base directive's content. The best it can seemingly do is add the inputs before or after the container which isn't ideal in terms of extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ng-content in your template

The content you place inside the components tag will appear where you have the ng-content

```
<your-component>
  This content will appear where the ng-content tag is in your component's template
</your-component>
```

or you can pass in a template

In your component you can have an input that takes a template

```
@Input()
myTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and in the template

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate" *ngIf="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```

and you can pass it in with

```
<your-component [myTemplate]="someCOntentTemplate"></your-component>
<ng-template #someCOntentTemplate>
  This content will be passed to the component
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Are these features part of angular1.x?

Comment: Yes, I can't remember the syntax. I haven't looked at Angular 1 for a few years now but templates and projection are definitely supported concepts.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is actually ng transclude in 1.x. I did try transclude but didn't try to include the base content in the ng transclude div. I wonder if I can include all the content from the base template there so that the additional items are added in the same content area. I'll try this tomorrow.